# How to include class dependency jar in JRuby?

Tags: ruby, jruby

I'm having trouble figuring out how to include/import/require `mydependency.jar` which `MyJavaClass` (within a `MyJavaClass.class` file) depends on. `MyJavaClass` contains many `import` statements importing classes from `mydependency.jar`. Everything is in the same directory.

When I run `java -cp '.:mydependency.jar' MyJavaClass` on the command line, I get no error and by putting some calls in `main` I can get it to run how I want, but when I run `ruby my_ruby_file.rb` with JRuby on the command line I get `NoClassDefFoundError` for the first class imported (which is being imported from `mydependency.jar`) within the `MyJavaClass.class` file. The stack trace for the error points to the `java_import` line in `my_ruby_file.rb` so it seems like it's not properly finding the classes imported from `mydependency.jar` that are included in my `MyJavaClass.class` file, even though it runs fine in the normal Java environment.

```
# contents of my_ruby_file.rb

require 'java'
require './mydependency.jar'

java_import 'MyJavaClass'

MyJavaClass.new.myJavaInstanceMethod('argument')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My `$CLASSPATH` environment variable was not set, which it needs to be in order for JRuby to be able to find my `jar`. After I ran `export CLASSPATH=".:mydependency.jar"` on the command line and removed the line `require './mydependency.jar'`, it worked.

Comment: I expect that the following would also work `CLASSPATH="."` and keep the require